# Finding $x$-intercept of a chord vertically spliting the circle into two parts

Tags: geometry, circles

Suppose we have a circle whose origin is at $(0,0)$ and its radius is $r$. There is a vertical straight chord that cuts the circle in two parts, say the left part is the **left-ratio** and the right part is the **right-ratio** (They are both natural numbers).

From the information provided above, i.e. $r$, the left-ratio and the right-ratio, how do I figure out the **$x$-intercept** of the chord inside the circle?

Comment: Could you clarify your question?  What are they ratios of?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment#Area